# Bootstrap 3 Navbar dropdown-toggle disabling <a> tag href link

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, anchor

I am supporting a client's wordpress site. Their Menu was not working well and so I had to develop all new menu for them ( one that looks like the old menu but responsive). I could not update it to bootstrap 4 version for different reasons.

So, my issue is, it is working absolutely fine on big screens. But for smaller screens, I am not able to enable href links of  tags(dropdown-menu headers). How do I do that? I tried the following script:

```
$('.navbar-collapse .dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1400) { $(this).addClass('disabled');}
  else { $(this).removeClass('disabled'); }
});

 $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  $('.navbar-collapse .dropdown-toggle').click(function() { $(this).removeClass('disabled'); });
});
```

I used bootstrap walker class to develop this menu for wordpress.
Please Help! the website is : rafiki.ca

Thanks,
nskp

Comment: so you want to disable drop down value in mobile view?

Comment: Can someone help me on this? I still cant find the answer to this question. I wanted to display the submenu below dropdown header and delete hover in mobile so that it wont show up when touchd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```
$('.navbar-collapse .dropdown-toggle').hover(function() {
  if (document.documentElement.clientWidth > 1400) 
  { $(this).addClass('disabled');
  }
  else 
  {
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
       $(this).removeClass('disabled');
    else
      $(this).addClass('disabled');
  }
});

 $( window ).on( "orientationchange", function( event ) {
  $('.navbar-collapse .dropdown-toggle').click(function() { $(this).removeClass('disabled'); });
});
```

Comment: No. I want to enable href on anchor  tag, which is being interrupted/overridden by dropdown-toggle

Comment: But I have check code in desktop but it is disable dropdown in submenu.I have added code in https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/frDqh

Comment: I enabled anchor tag in bootstrap walker class. Desktop is no issue... for mobile the anchor href link gets disabled... I am not sure what is happening in the background ( if someone could help on that I highly appreciate it)

Comment: Is is possible to share website url?

Comment: Please look this url http://jsfiddle.net/qambtwxg/ I have added code in that link

Comment: No.. I tried it already the same thing... I dont want hover to work on mobile..I need that anchor tag link to b active on dropdown header as well on mobile

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194920/discussion-between-jinesh-and-naga).